# Удаленный доступ к ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

на клиентских машинах стоит убунту, можно или (если возможно, так как?) одновременно поменять заставку на всех машинах удаленно? (на заставке будет информация для клиентов).

Answer (score 2):

Напиши скриптик с  ssh на все твои хосты и

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///path/to/your/image.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Выяснить какой файлик является заставкой(locate, find в помощь) и поменять через scp.